# Fs incorrectly reads or saves file leading to NaN. How to deal with it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, fs

I'm using Fs to save some data in a file. I start by having 0 in the first line and 0 in the second line. Then I want to add by one the second line. And sometimes after some tries (random, sometimes 100 and sometimes 700) something happens leading to first empty line and NaN in the second one. The code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
  name: "testkom",
  aliases: [],
  async execute(message, args, client) {
    
      var data = fs.readFileSync('peakcommands.txt').toString().split("\n");
      
      data[1]++;
      var text = data.join("\n");



      fs.writeFile('peakcommands.txt', text, function (err) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      });


      message.channel.send (data[1]);

  }
}
```

Comment: Try console logging and tell us what `data[1]` logs before it goes to NaN

Comment: If you call `execute()` without waiting for the previous one to finish, you can get conflicts with two separate operations trying to read/write to the same file.  Note that your `execute()` function does not even tell the caller when it's done since `fs.writeFile()` is asynchronous.  If synchronous I/O is OK here, then try switching to `fs.writeFileSync()` instead.  Since that is blocking, that will prevent your own app from conflicting with itself when writing to that file.

Comment: Please show us the contents of `peakcommands.txt`

Comment: should specify the encoding - `fs.readFileSync('peakcommands.txt', 'utf8')`

Comment: You can also add the following diagnostics right after `data[1]++`.  `if (typeof data[1] !== "number") { console.log(data[1], data); }` to catch it in action and see what everything is at the point it's messed up.  My guess is that `data[1]` was not convertable into a number (not digits) so you NaN at that point.

Comment: jfriend00 solution with writeFileSync worked for now I think, we'll see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it could either be an encoding issue or possibly a data race.

To fix the possible race condition, switch `fs.writeFile` to `fs.writeFileSync`, which will assure that the file write is synchronous.

To fix the encoding issue, you can specify the encoding, like this:

```js
fs.writeFileSync('peakcommands.txt', 'utf8' text, function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
});
```

If nothing works, check the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

Comment: That seems to be working for now. Looping to 2000 previously instantly just made wrong values in the file. This one goes to 2000 without problem. What is the importance of encoding here? Seems to be working without it

Comment: Encoding could help with the data being written in some weird automatically assumed format. I wasn't sure that it would do anything, it's just normally a good idea to clarify encodings to get that possible bug out of the way.